# Grails default package name

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, spring-tool-suite, interactive-mode

I am new to Grails and I like it very much. I want to place my classes in packages like `org.company.project.module.model`. Its quite painful for to me to repeat `create-domain-class <package>.<class_name>`. Is there something like "package templates" or can I somehow "enter" (like `grails cd org.comopany...`) and then just write Class names (`grails Person` will be generated in `./` location)? Is that possible or should I use `copy paste` design pattern?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 20):

If I understood your question, you are looking for default package name for your domain classes. In your `config.groovy` file there is a line saying:

```
grails.project.groupId = appName
```

if you give it an appName, Grails will use that as the default package name when it generates the artifacts.

```
grails.project.groupId = 'com.example.yourpackagename'
```

If you now create a domain class by default it will locate it under `com/example/yourpackagename`.

**UPDATE**

It is not required to use Grails commands like create-domain-class or other commands to create artifacts. These are all just classes that you can manually create.  Just create a file and duplicate it in the same package.

**UPDATE**

Grails interactive mode (when you type grails) for some of the commands by pressing `tab` it will type ahead the unique portion of the package name.

**UPDATE for Grails 3.0**

The setting has moved into `conf/application.yml`:

```
grails:
   profile: web
   codegen:
      defaultPackage: com.example.yourpackagename
```

Comment: Thanks for answer anyway when I want to put my controller into 'com.example.mypackagename.controllers' I have to write whole package. The command will place it in the groupId location, won't it?

Comment: That is correct, there will be some work, things might be easier with a IDE though.