# How to automatically import subpackages in a Grails project?

Tags: grails, ggts

How can I make my grails project automatically import subpackages such as org.myorg.appname.subpackage?

I have a standard grails project that I am building in GGTS. All of the classes so far are in a package name like org.myorg.appname. There are getting to be enough classes that I'd like to start subdividing this package further, such as org.myorg.appname.subpackage. However, only the org.myorg.appname package is automatically imported. How can I make additional packages be imported everywhere in my app?

Comment: Are you really sure that `org.myorg.appname` is automatically imported?  That surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

Grails doesn't have a place for you to tell it to import multiple packages. But it does have a default package, which in your case is *org.myorg.appname*.

When you create an artefact, like a controller, and don't specify a package (ex. grails create-controller blah), when the controller code gets generated there will be package statement that puts the generated artefact in the default package.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111582/grails-default-package-name).

So if you really want those subpackages you'll have to keep creating them manually. I used to do this but stopped because it wasn't worth it. An alternative is to just keep everything in the same package, or (my preferred method) refactor the app into multiple plugins, each with a different default package.